# List post from current taxonomy children

Tags: taxonomy, terms, children

I have a custom post type and a taxonomy with children, with a template file named taxonomy-productcategories.php. On this i want to list all children with their posts.

- Child taxonomy 1

  - Child taxonomy 1 Post A
  - Child taxonomy 1 Post B
  - Child taxonomy 1 Post C
- Child taxonomy 2

  - Child taxonomy 2 Post D
  - Child taxonomy 2 Post E
  - Child taxonomy 2 Post F

And so on...

I have an example for getting just the Child taxonomy, but i want to add the post from each taxonomy.

```
<?php
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$termchildren = get_term_children( $current_term->term_id, $taxonomyName );

foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    echo "$term->name:<br />"; 

}
?>
```

Comment: The solution I would go with is probably using [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) but that might be inefficient / slow but it would get the job done.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought too, som i looked fore that type of solution, but the only thing i found was geting it done with a specific post type and taxomony.

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea of combining the first code with this solution that lists posts from a specifik taxomony:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms('productcategories');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $wpq = array (
        'taxonomy'=>'productcategories',
        'term'=>$term->slug,
        'order'=>'asc',
        'orderby'=>'title');
        $query = new WP_Query ($wpq);
        echo "$term->name:<br />"; 
        ?>
        <?php
        if ($query->have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>, 
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php
        echo "<br />";   
    }
?>
```

I managed to combine the two, so this is my current solution. Maybe not the best but it works.

```
<?php 
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $current_term->term_id, $taxonomyName );
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
        $wpq = array (
        'taxonomy'=>$taxonomyName,
        'term'=>$term->slug,
        'order'=>'asc',
        'orderby'=>'title');
        $query = new WP_Query ($wpq);
        echo "$term->name:<br />"; 
        ?>

        <?php
        if ($query->have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>, 
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php
        echo "<br />";   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Instead of adding 2 answers, you should edit your first answer and append this code to it explaining the difference.

Comment: Done. Still working on a way to order the children. Right now i think it ordered bi ID.