# Taxonomy listing issue - does not display how I would like

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, listing

What I have is a:

- **Taxonomy**: menu_type

  - **Term**: drink (parent term)

    - **Sub term**: drink 1, drink 2 (child terms)
  - **Term**: appetizer (parent term)

    - **Sub term**: appetizer 1, appetizer 2 (child terms)

I want to go to the `drink` page and have it display like this - all the posts within that taxonomy:

- Drink

  - Drink 1

    - Drink 1 post
    - Drink 1 post
  - Drink 2

    - Drink 2 post
    - Drink 2 post

And the same for `appetizer`.

But, right now I get this:

- Drink

  - Drink 1 post
  - Drink 1 post
  - Drink 2 post
  - Drink 2 post

Here is my code:

```
/*
Template Name: taxonomy-menu_type
*/
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row page-title-row">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><span>Menu</span> | <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></h2>

            <?php if ( category_description() ) : // Show an optional category description ?>
                <p><?php echo category_description(); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid other-pgbody">
    <div class="row infor-row">
        <div class="container">

        <?php global $query_string;
        query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' ); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php
            $terms = get_terms($post->ID, "print_type");
            echo '<h3 class="child-term">'.$term->name.'</h3>';
            ?>

            <div class="col-sm-12 menu-list">

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 price-row col-md-6 clearfix">

                        <div class="item-price">
                            <?php if ($price = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_marvilmedia_price',true)): ?><?php echo '$'.$price; ?><?php endif; ?>   
                        </div>

                        <div class="item-info">
                            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span><br/>
                            <?php $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,'menu_side', '', ', ');
                            if (!empty($terms_as_text)) echo '', strip_tags($terms_as_text) ,''; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!--/table-->
            </div>

            <?php else :
                echo '<h2>No Menu Item for '.$term->name.'</h2>'; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row free-row">                
    </div>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**SOLVED**

I found the answer in another post that was answered by @Gustav for anyone looking a solution like you can follow the link or view the code below it works perfectly. [List post from current taxonomy children](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123059/list-post-from-current-taxonomy-children)

**THE WORKING CODE**

```
        <?php 
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $current_term->term_id, $taxonomyName );
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    $wpq = array (
    'taxonomy'=>$taxonomyName,
    'term'=>$term->slug,
    'order'=>'asc',
    'orderby'=>'title');
    $query = new WP_Query ($wpq);
    $taxonomy_img = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'tax-image', true );
    //echo "$term->name:<br />"; 
    ?>

    <div class="row infor-row">
    <div class="container">

    <?php echo '<h3 class="child-term">'.$term->name.'</h3>'; ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 menu-list">

    <?php if ($query->have_posts() ) : ?> 
    <?php while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 price-row col-md-6 clearfix">
    <div class="item-price"><?php if ($price = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_marvilmedia_price',true)): ?><?php echo '$'.$price; ?><?php endif; ?></div>
    <div class="item-info">
    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span><br/>
    <?php $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,'menu_side', '', ', '); if (!empty($terms_as_text)) echo '', strip_tags($terms_as_text) ,''; ?>
    </div>
    </div> 

    <?php endwhile; ?> 

    <!--/table-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row free-row" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $taxonomy_img; ?>');">                 
    </div>
    <?php else :
    echo '<h2>No Menu Item for '.$term->name.'</h2>'; ?> 
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php
    echo "";   
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I found the answer in another post that was answered by [@Gustav](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/42672/gustav)  for anyone looking a solution like you can follow the link or view the code below it works perfectly. [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123059/list-post-from-current-taxonomy-children](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/42672/gustav)

**THE WORKING CODE**

```
        <?php 
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $current_term->term_id, $taxonomyName );
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    $wpq = array (
    'taxonomy'=>$taxonomyName,
    'term'=>$term->slug,
    'order'=>'asc',
    'orderby'=>'title');
    $query = new WP_Query ($wpq);
    $taxonomy_img = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'tax-image', true );
    //echo "$term->name:<br />"; 
    ?>

    <div class="row infor-row">
    <div class="container">

    <?php echo '<h3 class="child-term">'.$term->name.'</h3>'; ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 menu-list">

    <?php if ($query->have_posts() ) : ?> 
    <?php while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 price-row col-md-6 clearfix">
    <div class="item-price"><?php if ($price = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_marvilmedia_price',true)): ?><?php echo '$'.$price; ?><?php endif; ?></div>
    <div class="item-info">
    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span><br/>
    <?php $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,'menu_side', '', ', '); if (!empty($terms_as_text)) echo '', strip_tags($terms_as_text) ,''; ?>
    </div>
    </div> 

    <?php endwhile; ?> 

    <!--/table-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row free-row" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $taxonomy_img; ?>');">                 
    </div>
    <?php else :
    echo '<h2>No Menu Item for '.$term->name.'</h2>'; ?> 
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php
    echo "";   
    }
    ?>
```